# How to assign hyperlink to records in datatable

Tags: jquery, jsp, datatable, datatables

I am new to JQuery. I am trying to create a datatable. All the functionality works very well. But in datatable records first column is userid, say 1,2,3 etc which are hyperlink to userprofile page. i.e. when click on 1, it will call /userprofile.jsp?id=1 ...I dont know how to make these changes,I have downloaded the Datatable plugin from this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/359750/jQuery-DataTables-in-Java-Web-Applications
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the aoColumns property with fnRender function to add custom columns. You can't use the Html.ActionLink helper because you have to generate the links dynamically from the javascript. The aoColumns property helps you to configure each columns, if you don't want to configure a particular column just pass null else you have to pass an object({}).

The fnRender function helps you to create the links using the values of the other columns. You can use the oObj.aData to get the values of the other column like id to generate the links.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
            bProcessing: true,         
            sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("Index1", "Default1")',
            aoColumns: [
                      null, // first column (RoleId)
                      null, // second column (RoleName)  
                      null, // third (UserId)
                      null, // fourth (UserName)

                      {     // fifth column (Edit link)
                        "sName": "RoleId",
                        "bSearchable": false,
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj)                              
                        {
                            // oObj.aData[0] returns the RoleId
                            return "<a href='/Edit?id=" 
                                + oObj.aData[0] + "'>Edit</a>";
                        }
                       },

                       { }, // repeat the samething for the details link

                       { }  // repeat the samething for the delete link as well

                   ]
     });  
}); 
</script>
```

Another important thing in the JSON output you return from the server, for the edit column also you have to return something like 1, 2, 3 or anything.

Reference: http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ajax-inlinebuttons.html

Comment: thanks for reply, I am using server side processing so all columns are populated from server side java class, will this work in that scenario as well?